# How can I locally download my canvas as a PNG, it's always returning a blank image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to download the contents of my canvas, but I keep getting a blank image PNG.

```
    <html>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <img id="source" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg" width="300" height="227">
    </div>
</body>

<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const image = document.getElementById('source');

image.addEventListener('load', e => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
});

function SaveCanvasToFile(myFileName) 
{
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.textContent = 'download image';
   link.href = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
   link.download = myFileName;
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
   document.body.removeChild(link);    
}
SaveCanvasToFile("test")
</script>

</html>
```

How can I download the contents of my canvas as a visible png?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="button" id="btndownload">Save</a>
```

First create a link.Then try this code...

```
var button = document.getElementById('btndownload');
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    button.href = dataURL;
});
```